# Exchange of limits in 2 variable sequence

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, multivariable-calculus

Let us say that a sequence $a_{nm}$ of real numbers indexed by pairs of positive integers $(n,m)$ *converges to $L$* if and only if for every $\epsilon\gt 0$ there exists $N\gt 0$ such that for all $n,m\geq N$, $|a_{nm}-L|\lt \epsilon$.

We'll write this condition  $$\lim_{m,n} a_{m,n} = L $$

Is it true that

$$ \lim_m \lim_n a_{m,n} = \lim_n \lim_m a_{m,n} = L \,\,\,\,\, \Rightarrow \,\,\,\,\, \lim_{m,n} a_{m,n} = L $$

?

What if $ a_{m,n} $ is a positive sequence?

Comment: What have you been able to show so far?

Comment: Well the converse is obviously true. I also know that this result holds when there's uniform convergence. I suspect this to be false but I don't know a counterexample.

Comment: Would this be a counterexample? I'm supposing both limits are the same $L$.

Comment: My question is NOT simply "can I exchange the limits?"

Comment: No, existence and equality of the iterated limits is never enough to prove convergence of the double limit. The double limit requires that every direction of approach to the limit point converges to the same value. Equality of the iterated limits only shows that two approaches agree.

Comment: Ok, so you're telling me that it works exactly like limits of two real variables $\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (x_0,y_0)} f(x,y) $, right? Could you help me find a counterexample, possible with a positive sequence?

Comment: Oh, well, the answer is exceptionally trivial: I can take $a_{m,m}=\delta_{m,n}$

Comment: Yes. Any counter-example for the real case provides counter-examples for the sequential case. Just have $a_{nm} = f(b_n, c_m)$, where $b_n \to x_0, c_m \to y_0$.

Comment: Oh. That was obvious... Silly question, I don't know why I wasn't convinced that it wasn't quite the same: thanks!